How many Jews should live in Exile?
1-God said:

But if you do not obey Me and do not observe all these commandments... [Lev. 26:14] I will scatter you among the nations... [Lev. 26:33]

2-The Talmud says:

Rabbi Osha'ya said... The Holy One, Blessed be He, performed a charitable deed toward Israel in that He scattered them among the nations.  [Had He exiled them to a single place, they could all have been destroyed at one time]. [Pesachim 87b, also Midrash Lekach Tov]

3-When the State of Israel was founded in 1948, it had 600,000 Jews, or only 5% of the total post-Holocaust worldwide Jewish population of 12 million.  In 2023 Israel had 7.2 million Jews, or 46% of the worldwide Jewish population of 15.7 million (according to the Jewish Agency for Israel).
4-The fraction of Jews in Israel has been steadily increasing. This is worrisome, per the Talmud.  Israel is a tiny country surrounded by implacable enemies that pose a daily existential threat, and we live in the age of nuclear weapons.  As a past president of rabidly-antisemitic Iran said, “Israel is a one-nuclear-weapon country”.  And Iran is building that nuclear weapon for that purpose.
5-Now, our hope for millennia has been to end the Exile and for all of us to return to the Land of Israel.  The prophet Isaiah predicted that the Messiah will first usher in a world of peace, then lead the Jewish exiles back into the Land of Israel, where they would not be threatened since there would be peace in the world.  [Isaiah 11:1-13]
Given all that, and before the Messiah arrives, what fraction of the Jews of the world should live in the Land of Israel, the rest living in the diaspora?  I know the Satmar, Neturei Karta and company want to wait for the Messiah in the diaspora, but how do our mainline commentators answer this question?

The entire question seems to be predicated upon seeing 2 as a prescription rather than a silver lining. There are advantages and disadvantageous to living in a diaspora. Just because our Sages in their wisdom recognized the advantages of the diaspora doesn't mean that they saw it as something that we should self reinforce.

Re: 5, we don't know what the sequence of events will be nor do we have a tradition regarding such details (שדברים סתומין הן אצל הנביאים. גם החכמים אין להם קבלה בדברים אלו H. Melakhim 12). We should not be ordering our lives around our speculative understanding of the order of the messianic era.

@Deuteronomy -- "There are advantages and disadvantages to living in a diaspora."  Indeed there are, whence my question.

Doesn't the Torah prescribe that all Jews who can should live in Israel? There are so many sources showing so that R Dov Lipman was able to write an entire book about it

@mbloch -- Whether living in Israel is a commandment is in dispute. The Ramban says yes, the Rambam says no (see their lists of 613).

This is a comment not an answer but too long to write in the comment section.
The question in general follows the anti-Zionist viewpoint that  Zionism and Jews settling in Israel put Jews in danger therefore it should be opposed. The OP brings a proof for it from the Gemora which says The Holy One, Blessed be He, performed a charitable deed toward Israel in that He scattered them among the nations. [Had He exiled them to a single place, they could all have been destroyed at one time]
That Gemora in itself does not mention and does not lead to asking that question about Eretz Yisroel. You can just as easily ask what fraction of Jews should live anywhere prior to Mosiach given the safety to being scattered around.  100 years ago the Zionist movement was getting  it's momentum from the danger facing Jews who were NOT living in Eretz Yisroel.
The Chofetz Chaim told people who were facing the danger in Europe before WII that they should go to Eretz Yisreol because there it will be safe prior to mosiach coming based on the posuk in Ovadia 1:17 which says  וּבְהַ֥ר צִיּ֛וֹן תִּֽהְיֶ֥ה פְלֵיטָ֖ה And on Mount Zion there shall be a remnant You would need someone like him to answer this question about today as well.
